# How to wait for all files and copy into dir

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have 3 files which will come everyday with date in file name.
I need to check all 3 files date if matching with today's date.
and need to wait for 3 files, because all files may not come at same time.
if all file arrives then only need to copy all 3 files to target directory.

below sample code is working for all files if available. but i need to make some while loop or something sleep command where my script can wait/look for all 3 files in src dir then move all together.

```
#!/bin/ksh
src_dir=/data/SIN/src;
tgt_dir=/data/SIN/tmp;
cd $src_dir;
RUN_DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`;

file1=file1_${RUN_DATE}.txt
file2=file2_${RUN_DATE}.txt
file3=file3_${RUN_DATE}.txt

file_count=`ls -lrt ${src_dir}/*.txt | grep $RUN_DATE | wc -l` ;

if [ "$file_count" == 3 ]
then
        echo "all 3 files are available";
        cp ${src_dir}/${file1} $tgt_dir;
        cp ${src_dir}/${file2} $tgt_dir;
        cp ${src_dir}/${file3} $tgt_dir;
    echo "files copied";
else
        echo "file missing";
fi
```

Comment: If you know all three filenames, then just test for existence of those three filenames.

Comment: you could try `sleep 60 && sh basename "$0"` ` instead of `echo "file missing"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close, just switching your `if` statement with a `while` loop, or just adding a while loop as you suggest should do the trick for you.

```
#!/bin/ksh
src_dir=/data/SIN/src;
tgt_dir=/data/SIN/tmp;
cd $src_dir;
RUN_DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`;

file1=file1_${RUN_DATE}.txt
file2=file2_${RUN_DATE}.txt
file3=file3_${RUN_DATE}.txt

file_count=`ls -lrt ${src_dir}/*.txt | grep $RUN_DATE | wc -l` ;

# check every 5 seconds if the files are all there
while [ "$file_count" -ne 3 ]; do
    sleep 5
    file_count=`ls -lrt ${src_dir}/*.txt | grep $RUN_DATE | wc -l`
done

if [ "$file_count" == 3 ]
then
    echo "all 3 files are available";
    cp ${src_dir}/${file1} $tgt_dir;
    cp ${src_dir}/${file2} $tgt_dir;
    cp ${src_dir}/${file3} $tgt_dir;
    echo "files copied";
else
    echo "file missing";
fi
```

This would work, though it would hang should there ever be more than 3 files in that dir, or if one or more of the files never turn up. So I'd recommend adding a break to the while loop:

```
# check every 5 seconds if the files are all there, up to 10 times
count=0
while [ "$file_count" -ne 3 ]; do
    sleep 5
    file_count=`ls -lrt ${src_dir}/*.txt | grep $RUN_DATE | wc -l`
    found_files=$(ls -lrt ${src_dir}/*.txt | grep $RUN_DATE)
    echo -e "files found:\n\t$found_files" # print the files that have been found so you know which are missing
    ((count++))
    if [ "$count" = 10 ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: thanks everyone....  both of you answer is correct. i was new for loop, so have idea but no proper syntax knowledge ... thanks for helping..... just need to know if i can print the file name in console which one is missing in that loop while check the names..... i have 3 files so which one is missing i need to print there... thanks in advance

Comment: I've edited my answer, so that it will print the files that have been found, so you know which are missing whilst the while loop is running.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
file_count=$(ls -lrt ${src_dir}/*.txt | grep -c $RUN_DATE)

while [ "$file_count" != 3 ]
do
    echo "file missing";
    sleep 60
    file_count=$(ls -lrt ${src_dir}/*.txt | grep -c $RUN_DATE)
else
        echo "all 3 files are available";
        cp ${src_dir}/${file1} $tgt_dir;
        cp ${src_dir}/${file2} $tgt_dir;
        cp ${src_dir}/${file3} $tgt_dir;
    echo "files copied";
    return

done
```

note that

- it is a bad idea to parse ls's output, unless you sure you don't hava any funny char (space, new line ...)
- I replaced `grep | wc -l` by `grep -c` which do the same
- In same way I replaced back quote by `$( )`

---

Edit : which file is missing ?

replace

```
echo "file missing";
```

by

```
test -f ${src_dir}/${file1} || echo ${file1} missing
test -f ${src_dir}/${file2} || echo ${file2} missing
test -f ${src_dir}/${file3} || echo ${file3} missing
```

Comment: thanks for help.....both of your answer is correct. i was new for loop, so have 
 little idea but no proper syntax knowledge ... thanks for helping..... just need to know if i can print the file name in console which one is missing in that loop while check the names..... i have 3 files so which one is missing i need to print there... thanks in advance